# Wget and curl can work normally, but ping fails

Tags: centos, networking, ping

When I ping www.google.com and 8.8.8.8, I get no reply:

```
# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.221.228) 56(84) bytes of data.
( no response)

# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
( no response)

20 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 19006ms
```

There has been no response.
But, both curl and wget are OK. My OS is CentOS 7.

Here is my network configuration file:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33 
TYPE=Ethernet
#BOOTPROTO=dhcp
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
#IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPADDR=192.168.42.12
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.42.129
DNS1=192.168.42.129
DNS2=114.114.114.114
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=ens33
UUID=e7328f29-6313-4382-8023-b7740ed4f7ad
ONBOOT=yes
```

Here is ip  and route information:

```
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:4d:df:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.42.12/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global ens33
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe4d:dfbf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
# ip route
default via 192.168.42.129 dev ens33  proto static  metric 100 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 
10.8.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1 
192.168.42.0/24 dev ens33  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.42.12  metric 100
```

```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep echo
```

outputs nothing.

I see, not be able to connect to Google because of the firewall:GFW.

traceroute output:

```
# traceroute -T www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (216.58.197.100), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.42.129)  0.541 ms  0.378 ms  0.294 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

traceroute with www.vim.org output:

```
     # traceroute -T www.vim.org
traceroute to www.vim.org (216.34.181.97), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.42.129)  0.447 ms  0.419 ms  0.287 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  vhost.sourceforge.net (216.34.181.97)  229.060 ms  214.904 ms  220.727 ms
```

But , ping www.vim.org  also have no response.

```
# ping www.vim.org
PING vhost.sourceforge.net (216.34.181.97) 56(84) bytes of data.
(no response)
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: This is a firewall issue blocking ICMP, either flush your iptables (`iptables - F` etc) or contact the net administration.

Comment: @Pandya, cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep echo  output nothing

Comment: @Torxed,i stop firewalld , problems still in

Comment: try:   `traceroute -T www.google.com`

Comment: @sis: Since we have no idea on what your network topology looks like. I'm guessing you're running a VirtualBox/VMware thing? If not, please give us a clue to what your network setup looks like and who owns `192.168.42.129`?

Comment: Yes ,@Torxed ,I running a VMware and   connected network by bridged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ping uses the ICMP protocol and ICMP traffic may be blocked on your network. Try tracepath and traceroute using tcp/udp.

Tracroute using tcp:

```
    traceroute -T www.google.com
```

should work.

Also check if your firewall is blocking ICMP.

```
   #service iptables stop
```

OR.

```
  #systemctl stop firewalld.service
```

and then try again using ping

If the problem still exists then ICMP traffic is blocked on your network level and ask your network admin.

**Some troubleshooting with ICMP on local system:**

To check whether ICMP is enabled or disabled run the command:

```
 cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

The output is 0 or 1:

```
0 means that ICMP is enabled
1 means that ICMP is disabled
```

If it's disabled and you want to enable it:

```
change 1 to 0 in the above file

Or run the command:

iptables  -I  INPUT  -i  ech0  -p   icmp  -s  0/0  -d  0/0   -j  ACCEPT
```

But you check that you are connected to the internet even if ICMP is blocked by using:

```
   nc -vz google.com 80
```

Comment: @ljaz Khan , than you for advice.  I have already stopped the firewall （firewalld and iptables）, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Did you try the traceroute command as above? i want to see the output of that command

Comment: Answer updated , try that again

Comment: @sis The firewall does not have to be on your server; it could be your provider, your router, or some other external entity.

Comment: Many corporate firewalls block ICMP - which is the protocol is used by ping utility.

Comment: @ljaz Khan, question updated  .   cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all  output is 0

Comment: Ok , then i am sure that ICMP is blocked by your corporate firewall