# traceroute: invalid option -- 'T' (Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: ubuntu, traceroute

I am trying to get traceroute installed with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute 
$ traceroute --version
traceroute (GNU inetutils) 1.9.4
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

to work over TCP on Ubuntu 19.10 but it gives:

```
$ traceroute -T google.com
traceroute: invalid option -- 'T'
Try 'traceroute --help' or 'traceroute --usage' for more information.
```

Strange since this post:

[Wget and curl can work normally, but ping fails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253339/wget-and-curl-can-work-normally-but-ping-fails)

says that should be a valid option.

But I don't find **-T** that on my system/version of traceroute:

```
$ traceroute --help
Usage: traceroute [OPTION...] HOST
Print the route packets trace to network host.

  -f, --first-hop=NUM        set initial hop distance, i.e., time-to-live
  -g, --gateways=GATES       list of gateways for loose source routing
  -I, --icmp                 use ICMP ECHO as probe
  -m, --max-hop=NUM          set maximal hop count (default: 64)
  -M, --type=METHOD          use METHOD (`icmp' or `udp') for traceroute
                             operations, defaulting to `udp'
  -p, --port=PORT            use destination PORT port (default: 33434)
  -q, --tries=NUM            send NUM probe packets per hop (default: 3)
      --resolve-hostnames    resolve hostnames
  -t, --tos=NUM              set type of service (TOS) to NUM
  -w, --wait=NUM             wait NUM seconds for response (default: 3)
  -?, --help                 give this help list
      --usage                give a short usage message
  -V, --version              print program version
```

Works fine *without* **-T**

```
$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (216.58.213.206), 64 hops max
  1   x.x.x.x  8.310ms  8.447ms  8.461ms 
   ...
 10   x.x.x.x  22.349ms  18.459ms  21.743ms
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the `traceroute` package which provide the modern `traceroute` command:

```
sudo apt install traceroute
sudo apt remove inetutils-traceroute
```

Or -without removing `inetutils-traceroute`- you can use `sudo update-alternatives --config traceroute` to switch between  `traceroute` versions.

Comment: Ah that works, requires sudo though. I also found `tcptraceroute` which works without sudo.